# kde4-config shows no output

Tags: 14.04, kde4

I installed kde4 following the instructions here (http://www.enqlu.com/2014/03/how-to-install-kde-4-12-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts.html)

But I get no output when I enter the command kde4-config

I am trying to get started with Open Source so decided to start by solving bugs on bugs.kde.org
The particular one I thought of solving needs me to get my copy of okular ready. I am following the instructions at the end here(https://okular.kde.org/download.php), So I need to get kde4 running

I executed

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

This is what i get when I try to get the installtion path

```
$ kde4-config  
$
```

Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

**KDE version for the Ubuntu 14.04LTS**

Available:

- 4.13: http://www.kubuntu.org/news/kde-sc-4.13.3
- 4.14: http://www.kubuntu.org/news/kde-sc-4.14

The KDE/Kubuntu desktops are metapackages: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages

There are several ways to install the KDE desktop:

- kde-plasma-desktop
- kde-standard
- kde-full
- kubuntu-desktop
- kubuntu-full
- etc...

Ubuntu Community - Installing Software: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware

To use the kde4-config add an option:

**kde4-config --help**

```
:~$ kde4-config --help
Usage: kde4-config [Qt-options] [KDE-options] [options] 

A little program to output installation paths

Generic options:
  --help                    Show help about options
  --help-qt                 Show Qt specific options
  --help-kde                Show KDE specific options
  --help-all                Show all options
  --author                  Show author information
  -v, --version             Show version information
  --license                 Show license information
  --                        End of options

Options:
  --expandvars              Left for legacy support
  --prefix                  Compiled in prefix for KDE libraries
  --exec-prefix             Compiled in exec_prefix for KDE libraries
  --libsuffix               Compiled in library path suffix
  --localprefix             Prefix in $HOME used to write files
  --kde-version             Compiled in version string for KDE libraries
  --types                   Available KDE resource types
  --path type               Search path for resource type
  --locate filename         Find filename inside the resource type given to --path
  --userpath type           User path: desktop|autostart|document
  --install type            Prefix to install resource files to
  --qt-prefix               Installation prefix for Qt
  --qt-binaries             Location of installed Qt binaries
  --qt-libraries            Location of installed Qt libraries
  --qt-plugins              Location of installed Qt plugins
```

Development/CMake/Addons for KDE: https://techbase.kde.org/Development/CMake/Addons_for_KDE

```
The locations of install directories

They are all interpreted relative to CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX

BIN_INSTALL_DIR - the directory where executables be installed (default is prefix/bin)
SBIN_INSTALL_DIR - the directory where system executables will be installed (default is prefix/sbin)
LIB_INSTALL_DIR - the directory where libraries will be installed (default is prefix/lib)
```

**kde4-config with the cmake**

The kde4-config can be used with the cmake.

An generic example:

```
mkdir -p builddir
cd builddir && cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=`kde4-config --prefix`
make
sudo make install
```

With the Ubuntu the:

```
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=`kde4-config --prefix`
```

is same as:

```
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
```

**More links**

- KDE install dirs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254976/kde-install-dirs
- Configuring KDE paths: http://blog.davidedmundson.co.uk/blog/set-kde-paths

Comment: I believe I did install kde4 but I don't understand how do I use it or get it's installation path to use in this command
    cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/your/kde4/install/dir

Comment: With the Ubuntu it is '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr' Added a generic cmake example.